# pytest check columns returned

Tags: python, pytest

I'm having an issue figuring out how to run this. I'm trying to create a test dataframe against which I can test the output of a method.

```
@pytest.fixture
def keyword():
    return ['bitcoin']


@pytest.fixture
def start():
    return '2020-06-05T01'


@pytest.fixture
def end():
    return '2020-06-05T04'


@pytest.fixture
def df():
    df = pd.DataFrame(['2020-06-05 01:01:00', '1591318860',
                       'Jun 4, 2020 at 7:01 PM',
                       '7:01 PM', '[71]', '[True]', '[71]'],
                      index=['date'],
                      columns=['time', 'formattedTime', 'formattedAxisTime',
                      'value', 'hasData', 'formattedValue'])

    return df


def test__get_cookies():
    """check if hardcoded values are True"""
    pytrends = GoogleTrends()
    assert pytrends.cat == 0
    assert pytrends.gprop == ''
    assert 'NID' in pytrends.cookies.keys()


def test__dict_request(keyword, start, end, df):
    """test the dict functionality"""
    pytrends = GoogleTrends()
    data = pytrends.interest_over_time(kw_list=keyword, start_date=start, end_date=end)  # noqa E501
    assert data.columns.equals(df)
```

This gives me an error with the pytest. I'm pretty new to python, and even less experience with pytest. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Can you post the error you get when you run this? Hard to know exactly how to help you without that!

Comment: Also where is this `GoogleTrends` class from? Are you using any library beyond `pandas` and `pytest`?

Comment: ==================================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================================== 
ERROR test_google_trends_utility.py::test__dict_request - ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (1, 6)

Comment: Google Trends is a class I made. It is what I am testing: 

`import pandas as pd

import pytest

from google_trends_utility import GoogleTrends

`

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I added this to the question directly so it's easier to see the big picture. Please see my answer below, I think I found what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is in the initialization of the `pd.DataFrame` object.

The error message says: `Shape of passed values is (7, 1), indices imply (1, 6)` which indicates you need to pass the data differently.

I founds two issues in the payload you pass:

1. `'[71]'` seems to be duplicated
2. You're passing a list of values, but you should pass a list of tuples where each tuple has exactly the same size as the number of columns.

It's hard to understand without an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        (  # Notice the tuple here, inside the list
            "2020-06-05 01:01:00",
            "1591318860",
            "Jun 4, 2020 at 7:01 PM",
            "7:01 PM",
            "[71]",  # Notice this value appears only once
            "[True]",
        )
    ],
    index=["date"],
    columns=[
        "time",
        "formattedTime",
        "formattedAxisTime",
        "value",
        "hasData",
        "formattedValue",
    ],
)
```

(reformatted so it's easier to understand what's going on).

If you initialize the dataframe like that, the error goes away, and you get a dataframe like this:

```
                     time formattedTime       formattedAxisTime    value hasData formattedValue
date  2020-06-05 01:01:00    1591318860  Jun 4, 2020 at 7:01 PM  7:01 PM    [71]         [True]
```

Not sure it'll fix your test though :)

Comment: Looking at the shape of your data, it's possible the problem is also a missing `date` column. I realize now that `value` and `formattedValue` might have been `[71]`.